# SelectList Dropdowns in C# (Selected value)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

Ok I have the following Code

```
   #region getDurationListDD
    private List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> getDurationListDD
    {
        get
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> dDur = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
            dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(2, 2));
            dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(3, 3));
            dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(4, 4));
            dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(7, 7));
            dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(14, 14));
            dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(21, 21));

            return dDur;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Then the following in the main ActionResult...

```
ViewData["changeDuration"] = new SelectList(getDurationListDD, "Key", "Value", Duration);
```

this on the view

```
Html.DropDownList("changeduration", (SelectList)ViewData["changeDuration"])
```

Now if the Duration was set (i.e. int Duration = 7;) then I'd expect that 7 would be selected, but for some reason it isn't. Any hints before I give up trying and do something more productive?

Ta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fixed it.

Changed:

```
Html.DropDownList("changeduration", (SelectList)ViewData["changeDuration"])
```

To:

```
Html.DropDownList("cduration", (SelectList)ViewData["changeDuration"])
```

Problem Solved

Comment: You may have had some sort of ambiguous name in your view or your viewdata and by changing to "cduration" you disambiguated the value.

Comment: Ye I'm guessing that the abiguous name was the use of changeDuration twice.

Comment: The model name can't be the same as the SelectList name. See my DDL tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx